# Redundant master slave system and Getting data from specific slave module

Tags: python, c, master-slave, rs485

I am dealing with Master-Slave model as follows:

```
  Person <-------- Master controller ---
                                        |                
                                        |----------|---------.......---------|   
                                     Slave1     Slave2                     SlaveN
```

Master is controller unit and slaves are DC-DC modules. Master and slave units communicates via Basic Serial Interface Protocol (BSIP) over RS485 interface or SCI interface. Master controller also gives data access to person using Modbus over Ethernet. 
The controller code is written in C language (via automatic code generation using python).

My question is :
What code should I write for developing master-slave communication so that I do not have to repeat same code for all slaves (redundancy). Also by doing this I also want to implement if a "Person" can access only data from the slave he asks for. For example if a "Person" wants some specific data from slave 3, what structure should I use?

Comment: What do you mean "What code should I write for developing master-slave communication"? Obviously you should write whatever is required from the protocol. The question is unclear and far too broad. Any why on earth is this tagged Python?

Comment: Too broad question. BTW you are using ModBus over Ethernet from person to Master. You can continue using ModBus RTU to slaves. Master could bridge requests from person to slaves and vice versa